# Google Sheets: how to create dropdown list using data from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to populate a drop down list in a cell (let's say cell B2) of Spreadsheet A (using data validation) on basis of data located in Spreadsheet B (range - C3:C15).
How do I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Getting the items from another workbook, as opposed to another sheet in the same workbook is similar.  It's a two-step process.  First, you need to import the data you want to use for the validation items into the workbook where you want to make use of it, then connect it up as described in @uselink126's answer.

An example: [Workbook 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EwEn_2dSbgAlR7jJ7UT_MyE3h1-Biq3qoovfIGUnVlo/edit?usp=sharing) contains a list of fruit names in no particular order.  The list has been assigned a named range `Fruits` for readability, but this isn't necessary. [Workbook 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QvDcIJh1LQj2e39DVplFcQ4KDw-Hr3oiF1Qm9ObyT_U/edit?usp=sharing), Sheet 1 has a column of cells where we want to populate a drop-down with the items from Workbook 2.

**Step 1 - Importing the data**

- Add another sheet to Workbook 1 and insert the following formula into cell A1:

  ```
    =ImportRange("<key>","Sheet1!Fruits")
  ```

where `<key>` is the unique ID Google docs assigned when you created the spreadsheet.  In the example, the items are sorted into alphabetical order as part of the import, and to do this you would enter instead:

```
    =Sort (ImportRange("<key>","Sheet1!Fruits"), 1, true)
```

The `1,`  signifies column 1 is what to sort by, `true` means sort ascending.  The cells in column 1 should populate with the sorted fruits.

**Step 2 - Point the data validation to the imported list**

On Workbook 1, Sheet 1, Select the cells you want to have the fruits as their drop-down data source.

- Right-click the selection and click on `Data Validation` from the menu. Set `Criteria` to `Dropdown (from a range)` and enter `Sheet2!A1:A20`

That's it.  The drop-down chevrons should appear in those cells and when clicked the list of fruits should appear.

Note that this is "live" - adding an item of fruit to Workbook 2's list will also magically add it sorted in the drop-down list.

Comment: Is importing the data from the other workbook into this workbook really the only way to do it? I would like to avoid adding another sheet that does nothing except duplicate data from another workbook.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't get the drop-down items directly from another workbook, you need to import them into the workbook that you want to use them in.  A bit of a drag maybe, but getting the data from another workbook every time the user clicks the chevron is probably a bit more intensive than getting it from the same workbook.  Bear in mind that the validation source data range needn't be on another sheet - it can be the same sheet - i.e. the range could be `Sheet1!B1:B20` instead `Sheet2!A1:A20` but I think it's better to keep it out of sight/out of the way.

Comment: at the moment this solution gives 'Formula Parse Error'. You need to change the "," for ";".
So it will be like that: =IMPORTRANGE("<key>";"Sheet1!Fruits")

Comment: Weird.  It's working for me still on the example workbooks.  I tried making your change (using a delimiter `;` instead of `,`), and the Google parse police changed it back to `,`.

Answer (score 15):

The format to access cells from another spreadsheet in Google Sheets is:

```
SheetName!CellAddress
```

For example, let's say you have a Google Sheet that contains 2 spreadsheets named: `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` (The names are listed on the tabs at bottom left hand side of each sheet).

In `Sheet1` if you wanted to access cell `B2` in `Sheet2`, you reference it by inputting: `Sheet2!B2`

In `Sheet2` if you wanted to access cells `C3:C15` in `Sheet1` , you reference those cells by inputting: `Sheet1!C3:C15`

To specifically add cells from another sheet to a dropdown:

1) Select the cell you want the dropdown in

2) Right click on the cell and select Data Validation

3) In the dialog box, click the grid image in the Criteria input box

4) This will bring up the "What Data?" dialog box

5) Click on the tab for the sheet you want to access

6) Hold down shift and click on the cells you want to select (you will see the cell addresses show up in the input box in the "What Data?" dialog)

7) Click OK and you are set. The data will update if you make changes in the source sheet.

More info: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en

Comment: Sorry, probably I didn't express myself clear enough in the question. What I ment is: I needed to take data from Book A and use it for populating dropdown menu in Book B (another **file** on my Google drive), not use data from another sheet of the same book (file). That project is complete - we used another approach. Thank you for your answer - it is correct for the stated question.

Comment: @keshet, you should accept rossmcm's answer. It is appropriate to situation.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore: `Sheet1!C3:C15`. I'd like to reference a range from another worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to rossmcm's answer but with a few tweaks because his answer didn't work for me:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url; range_string)
```

Where `spreadsheet_url` is The full URL of the spreadsheet from where data will be imported, and `range_string` a string, of the format "[sheet_name!]range" (e.g. "Sheet1!A2:B6" or "A2:B6") specifying the range to import.

Example:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EwEn_2dSbgAlR7jJ7UT_MyE3h1-Biq3qoovfIGUnVlo/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A1:A7")
```

More info [from Google DOCS Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en&authuser=0)!

Answer (score 0):

I have two sheets

SheetA and SheetB

SheetA contains the data and ColumnA1 is where I wish to do validations.
SheetB contains all the data against which validation is needed and stored in Column ColumnB1
For Ex: Expense Categories

- Select Entire ColumnA1 in SheetA and click Data->Data Validation
- In `Apply to Range` ensure you select entire ColumnA1
- In `Criteria` select `Dropdown(from a range)` and in there select entire ColumnB1 of SheetB
- Click Done.